# Conditional Probability given two Coins

Tags: probability

Coin 1 is fair. When flipped it has a probability of 0.5 for heads and 0.5 for tails. Coin 2 is biased. When flipped it has a probability of 0.9 for heads and 0.1 for tails.

You grab one of these two coins at random (equally likely that you grabbed coin 1 or 2) and you flip it. What's the probability it comes up heads?

Answer (score 1):

The chance is is $0.5(0.5)+0.5(0.9)=0.7$.

Comment: chance of picking coin 1 x coin 1 chance of heads + chance of picking coin 2 x coin 2 chance of head